# No javadoc for Java API in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

All my javadoc/method description information in Netbeans has suddenly dissapeared,

[image]

I'm not able to find any other cases on Stack Overflow of other people having this issue, but has anyone else maybe had this problem and figured it out, or know what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Did you upgrade your JDK and not install the source code?

Comment: I havn't switched JDK or JRE any time recently. I've played with setting classpaths to use `java` and `javac` from cmd, could that have done it?

Comment: & Is there a way I can reinstall the javadoc info?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Eclipse today so hopefully this helps out.

If you go to Tools - Java Platforms, what does it show?  It should show your current Java JDK.  If not:

1) Verify that you have a JDK installed under C:\Program Files\Java\ or C:\Program Files (x86)

2) If so, select Add Platform and add the JDK folder (e.g. jdk1.8.0_25) back to your platform list

3) If not, re-download and install the JDK and do step 2

Also, you should be able to right click on your Java Project, go to Libraries, and see the current JDK (Java Platform) that is being used.

Comment: Its showing my current JDK in Java Platforms, and the Libraries menu in my project properties is also showing my JDK selected... I might need to reinsall the JDK I guess